# A **proof** for $\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}{\frac{1}{t+3i}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing

I need a **proof** for the inequality:
$\sum_{i=0}^{t-2}{\frac{1}{t+3i}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$
for all natural numbers $t \geq 2$. For $t=2$ both sides are equal.

Can someone find a **proof** for all $t$? maybe by **proving** monotonicity (non-increasing) in $t$?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit overkill but well...

Check it is true for $t < 27$ or so. Then assuming $t \geq 27\ (*)$ :
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{t-2} \frac{1}{t+3i} = \frac{1}{t} + \sum_{i=1}^{t-2} \frac{1} {t+3i} \leq \frac{1}{t} + \int_0^{t-2} \frac{1}{t+3x} \ dx = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{3} log(4 - 6/t) \leq \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{3}log(4) \overset{(*)}{\leq} \frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $t=2.25$ the sum seems to be greater than $\dfrac{1}{2}$
The sum has a maximum between $0.368\lt t\lt 0.369$ and I think is greater than $0.5$

Comment: I think $t$ is a natural number.

Comment: @Roby5: in this case it needs to specify $t\in\mathbb{N}$ in the question

Comment: How do you sum from 0 to $t-2$ when $t$ is not natural?

Comment: @user1247378: Ok. It could solve the problem

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra Do you have a suggestion how? :) Proof-wise